# Node function works but is undefined when run via Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, twilio-api

I've already set up a working function using Twilio's API. The function works when I enter parameters through the UI, but when I run the test in Mocha it fails stating that the function is undefined. I also have one other test in Mocha that runs before this test and the first test passes.

twilioClient.js:

```
var config = require('./config');
var client = require('twilio')(config.accountSid, config.authToken);

sendSms = function(to, message) {
  client.messages.create({
    body: message,
    to: to,
    from: config.sendingNumber
    // mediaUrl: 'http://www.yourserver.com/someimage.png'
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Could not notify administrator');
      console.error(err);
      return 'Could not notify administrator';
    } else {
      console.log('Administrator notified');
      return 'Administrator notified';
    }
  });
};

module.exports.sendSms = sendSms;
```

My indexSpec.js file:

```
var chai= require('chai');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var twilioNotifications = require('./Send Text/js/twilioNotifications');
var cfg = require('./Send Text/js/config.js');
var twilio = require('twilio');
var tClient = require('./Send Text/js/twilioClient.js');

describe('TwilioVars', function() {
    it('returns true if variables are not null nor undefined', function() {
        var tVars = cfg.twilioVars(cfg.reqConfig);

        expect(tVars).to.equal(true);
    })
})

describe('MsgSent', function() {
    it('confirms if message can be sent', function() {
        var receiver = <my number>;
        var message = 'My message';
        var sentMsg = tClient.sendSms(receiver, message);   

        expect(sentMsg).to.equal('Administrator notified');
    })
})
```

My config.js file:

```
var cfg = {};
cfg.accountSid = <some string>;
cfg.authToken = <some string>;
cfg.sendingNumber = <some string>;

var requiredConfig = [cfg.accountSid, cfg.authToken, cfg.sendingNumber];

// For testing:
cfg.reqConfig = requiredConfig;
cfg.twilioVars = function(arr) {
    if (arr[0] && arr[1] && arr[2]) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
// End testing

var isConfigured = requiredConfig.every(function(configValue) {
  return configValue || false;
});

if (!isConfigured) {
  var errorMessage =
    'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN, and TWILIO_NUMBER must be set.';

  throw new Error(errorMessage);
}

// Export configuration object
module.exports = cfg;
```

Any insight as to why the function runs but why the test fails would be greatly appreciated.

P.s. The error is below:

```
 1) MsgSent confirms if message can be sent:
 AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'Administrator notified'
  at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\James Bradley\code_tests\twilio\twilio_test\indexSpec.js:22:22)
  at callFn (C:\Users\James Bradley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:326:21)
  at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\James Bradley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:319:7)
  at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\James Bradley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:422:10)
  at C:\Users\James Bradley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:528:12
  at next (C:\Users\James Bradley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:342:14)
  at C:\Users\James Bradley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:352:7
  at next (C:\Users\James Bradley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:284:14)
  at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\James Bradley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I figured it out. Had to create another async function to return a variable that was either 'Administrator notified' or 'Could not notify administrator'.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sendSms` function is probably asynchronous, you need to wait for it to complete before testing it's output. Consider adding a callback to that function that you can invoke when `client.messages.create()` makes its callback, and employ [done](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code). Or consider returning a promise from `sendSms`.

For example:

twilioClient.js:

```
...
sendSms = function(to, message, cb) {
  client.messages.create({
    ...
  }, function(err, data) {
    ...
    cb(err, data);
  });
};
```

indexSpec.js:

```
...
describe('MsgSent', function() {
  it('confirms if message can be sent', function(done) {
    ...
    var sentMsg = tClient.sendSms(receiver, message, function(err, data) {
      expect(data.sentMsg).to.equal('Administrator notified');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```